# Can't get ControlGet to work

Tags: autohotkey

Here's my script:

```
ControlGet, Output, Hwnd,,, ahk_id TV_REMOTEDESKTOP_CLASS1

MsgBox %Output%

PostClick(%Output%, 1170, 305, 10, 50)

PostClick(hwnd, X, Y, Count, Delay)
{
    p := y << 16 | (x & 0xffff)
    Loop, %Count% {
        PostMessage, 0x201, 1, p, , ahk_id %hwnd%
        If (Delay)
            Sleep Delay
        PostMessage, 0x202, 0, p, , ahk_id %hwnd%
        If (Delay)
            Sleep Delay
    }
}
```

And I can't get it to work!
I want to make it click on X Y pos, in a program that isn't visible/without moving mouse.

I could use Click, but then I'd have to have the program open AND it would move the mouse to each click.

PostClick function from: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/35742-postmessage-click-useful-hwnd-clicker/

I'm unsure how to do it.

edit:

```
ControlGet, chwnd, Hwnd,,, ahk_id TV_REMOTEDESKTOP_CLASS1
PostClick(chwnd, 1223, 395, 10, 50)

PostClick(hwnd, X, Y, Count, Delay)
{
    p := y << 16 | (x & 0xffff)
    Loop, %Count% {
        PostMessage, 0x201, 1, p, , ahk_id %hwnd%
        If (Delay)
            Sleep Delay
        PostMessage, 0x202, 0, p, , ahk_id %hwnd%
        If (Delay)
            Sleep Delay
    }
}
```

is my new code. (tried someones script)
My mouse positions according to au3_spy:

In Active Window: 1223, 395
On Screen: 1136, 398

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `PostClick(%Output%, 1170, 305, 10, 50)` is wrong because this is an expression (it's a function call, not a command) so the variable `Output` doesn't need `%`.
2. `ahk_id TV_REMOTEDESKTOP_CLASS1` is wrong, the control is specified without `ahk_id` and in a different position, see the documentation for [ControlGet](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ControlGet.htm).
3. By default the [last found window](http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#LastFoundWindow) is used so you need to specify which window to look for, for example using `ahk_class TV_CClientWindowClass`.
4. Also note that as per documentation, [WM_LBUTTONDOWN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645607(v=vs.85).aspx)'s (0x201) coordinates are relative to the control that receives the message. To calculate the relative coordinates subtract the top left corner coordinates of `TV_REMOTEDESKTOP_CLASS1` control from the absolute coordinates of the click point. For example, if the top left corner is (500,100) then (1170,305) would become (670,205).

---

Assuming (1170, 305) coordinates are already relative, the correct code would be:

```
DetectHiddenWindows, On
ControlGet, output, Hwnd, , TV_REMOTEDESKTOP_CLASS1, ahk_class TV_CClientWindowClass, TV_CClientToolBar
PostClick(output, 1170, 305, 10, 50)
```

Comment: How do I get the top corner coordinates etc.

Comment: Might be the control lol. Because under "Window Title & Class", the ahk_class is TV_CClientWindowClass - ClassNN is REMOTEDESKTOP thingy.

Comment: Problem with ^ is that I have two "programs" with the TV_CClientWindowClass

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90169/discussion-between-mathias-sjoberg-and-woxxom).